# In a jenkins job, I want to checkout two repo from different svn server, but failed

Tags: svn, jenkins, continuous-integration

all, 
      I created a jenkins job to build a module.(It's maven module)
      Our project's code will be checkout from two different svn servers. The servers have different username/password.
      When I configure the first svn server with correct username/password, and it works. But when I configure the second svn server with correct username/password, it always gave me the warning information. Jenkins told me that it can not access the svn server.
      Can you help me ?
Thanks
Steven
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You clicked "Enter Credentials" link and entered the second set of credentials, right?

Just change your input cursor focus. The red error message is generated when you focus away from the field. It will also be cleared when you focus away from the field. Click on any other editable field, and it should go away, then click Save.

If you still have issues, reply back here